# How to register post data in session before authentication in symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3

I need to store post client data in the session before any other action in symfony. When user is not authenticated, i lose the post client data because the redirection to login page.

How to do it correctly ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably add an exception listener service and watch for `AccessDeniedException` exceptions.

**config.yml**:

```
services:
  kernel.exception.listener:
    class: Acme\DefaultBundle\EventListener\ExceptionListener
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

**ExceptionListener.php**:

```
// ...
public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{
    $exception = $event->getException();

    if ($exception instanceof AuthenticationException || $exception instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
        // Do something with the POST data
        $postData = $event->getRequest()->request;
    }   
}
```